# rake aborted! no such file to load -- rush

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

I am using using rails 2.3.5 , ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]

I am on windows machine,

The project has no .gem file, so i use rake gems:install, and rake db:create

upto the above step everything is working fine, but

when i run **rake db:migrate --trace**, i get the following error

```
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rush
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`gem_original_require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/workspace/ruby/education/fedena2.3inprogress/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/d
elayed/worker.rb:1
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`gem_original_require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/workspace/ruby/education/fedena2.3inprogress/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/d
elayed_job.rb:6
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`gem_original_require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/workspace/ruby/education/fedena2.3inprogress/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/init.
rb:1:in `evaluate_init_rb'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:1
58:in `evaluate_init_rb'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:1
54:in `evaluate_init_rb'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:4
8:in `load'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/load
er.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/load
er.rb:37:in `each'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/load
er.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:36
9:in `load_plugins'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:16
5:in `process'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:11
3:in `send'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:11
3:in `run'
D:/workspace/ruby/education/fedena2.3inprogress/config/environment.rb:6
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`gem_original_require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_su
pport/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4

D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205
:in `call'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205
:in `execute'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200
:in `each'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200
:in `execute'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158
:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151
:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176
:in `invoke_prerequisites'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174
:in `each'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174
:in `invoke_prerequisites'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157
:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151
:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144
:in `invoke'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:94:in `top_level'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:94:in `each'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:94:in `top_level'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:88:in `top_level'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:66:in `run'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application
.rb:63:in `run'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/bin/rake:19:in `load'
D:/programfiles/Ruby187/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Comment: Have you tried "bundle install" ?

Comment: the project don't have .gem file , so i am unable to use bundle install , i tried running bundle install , it says Could not locate Gemfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems your application requires the gem `rush` [http://rubygems.org/gems/rush], which is missing. Follow the url to install it and try again.

Yes, `bundle install` should make sure to install all required gems in your system.

`gem install rush`, works or add gem rush to your gem file and then run bundle install (if you use bundler)

Comment: the project don't have .gem file , so i am unable to use bundle install , i tried running bundle install , it says Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: I tried gem install rush , now rake db:migrate works fine. Thanks Samiron